# My WordPress theme is hyphenating and can't turn it off using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woothemes

I'd like to stop the hyphenation on my WordPress site. Using the function theme from WooThemes.

I've added this to the `style.css` file in my child theme (note I added more specificity and the `!important` tags as it continued to not work).

```
html body #wrapper #content p {
    -moz-hyphens: none !important;
    -ms-hyphens: none !important;
    -webkit-hyphens: none !important;
    hyphens: none !important;
}
```

I can't even find this declaration over ruled in Firebug to understand why it's not working.

I've set up an example of what's going on over here: http://dev.thecyclery.net.au/home-test/hyphens/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a trailing slash in this comment that's breaking your CSS just enough to cause this problem.

```
/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- *//
```

That last slash on the very end, that's your culprit. Delete it and everything should work as expected. The comment should look like this:

```
/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks so much for finding that Chris... I feel a bit silly that it was such a tiny and simple thing!!!! I guess the fact that the rest of the CSS was working fine caused me to overlook something like this! Just out of interest, did you just happen across this error or is there a debugger I should be making use of?

Comment: @jonharris.photography, syntactic CSS errors can be detected using the checker http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ (and using a browser’s Developer Tools is useful, too).

Comment: Thanks @Jukka K. Korpela!